# Dectect which button and checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have,

```
<div>
  <span>Buttons</span>
    <div>
      <button id ="button_1" class="button">Btn 1</button><br />
      <button id ="button_1" class="button">Btn 2</button><br />
      <button id ="button_3" class="button">Btn 3</button><br />
      <button id ="button_4" class="button">Btn 4</button><br />
    </div>
  <span>Checkboxes</span>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /> Chbx 1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Chbx 2 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Chbx 3 <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I determine which button/checkbox has been clicked? I could attach a click event to each button but I'm looking for any method/tricks you might have that's a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach a click to *ALL* buttons and inputs and check the `tagName`, `ID` etc..

```
$(document).on('click', 'input, button', function(event) {
    alert(this.tagName + '#' + this.id);     
});
```

*NOTE:* You can attach the event to just the `document` element and check `event.target` to achieve the same, but the above is more efficient as the callback will be fired only for inputs and buttons instead of for all elements.

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vCjn9/

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are heaven sent.